# npm ERR! Error al tratar de ejecutar nmp install en Typescript

Tags: nodejs, typescript, npm, instalacion

Estoy estudiando un curso de Typescript en el que el profesor nos adjunta un archivo comprimido en el cual al extraerlo se encuentran todo lo que necesitamos para la lección. El problema surge cuando nos pide que ejecutemos en la terminal `npm install` y me salta el siguiente error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté buscar por todas partes cómo solucionarlo pero nada funcionó, incluso cambiarlo a otra carpeta para que no estuviera dentro del escritorio pero nada. Mi versión de node es la v16.17.0 y la de npm es la 8.15.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fíjate la ruta donde estas ejecutando el comando `npm install` es `../intento de solucion/ts-node` si no me equivoco la ruta correcta es `../intento de solucion/ts-node/ts-node`.

En la segunda carpeta `../ts-node/ts-node` dale click derecho y a la opción de abrir terminal (te va a abrir una terminal con la ruta hacia esa carpeta) y ejecutas el comando allí.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, era eso lo que estaba haciendo mal. Ya se instaló todo correctamente. ^^

Comment: Me alegro poder haberte ayudado :), agradezco si le das a la flecha hacia arriba para marcar como respuesta útil.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema principal es que la carpeta `ts-node` contiene, a su vez, tanto otra carpeta `ts-node`, como un `package-lock.json`. En tu cmd estás ejecutando el comando `npm install` en la carpeta que no contiene un package.json.

Debes abrir el proyecto desde la carpeta correcta, ejecutando el comando `cd ts-node` y luego hacer el `npm install` o, desde el propio cmd de VS Code, hacer `cd ts-node`y ejecutar el comando `npm install`.